# Why there are more than one “still running” instances

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I'm checking a server's reboot history by `last -x reboot`, the output is as following:

```
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Tue Sep 24 00:21   still running
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Fri Sep 20 07:48   still running
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Fri Sep 20 01:11 - 23:55  (-1:15)
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Thu Sep 19 23:28 - 17:17  (-6:10)
reboot   system boot  4.20.6-200.fc29. Wed Sep 18 20:12 - 15:34  (19:21)
```

Why there are two `still running` instances? According to my understanding, there should one and only one `still running` instance.

Comment: How are these entries are shown by `utmpdump < /var/log/wtmp` (latest is at the bottom), and what entries are in between them? Do any of them have a "zero" timestamp (showing 1970-01-01 or 1969-12-31)?

Comment: @grawity No, I didn't find those wired date. Maybe it's because last time shutdown happens unexpectedly? So the shutdown time is not logged onto `/var/log/wtmp`

Comment: It shouldn't be; as long as `lasttime` is non-zero, the program is supposed to report those entries as "crash" instead of "still running".